# Axios is not returning data from API because of bigger file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, file, axios

Axios is not returning data from API because of bigger file.

[image]

This is my code in api file:

```
/* Get the archive config information for the device from API */
const getConfigArchiveFileRawData = (deviceId, versionId, fileId) => {
    try {
        return axios({
            method: apiConstant.getMethod,
            url:
                apiConstant.urlArchiveConfigDeviceFileID +
                "/" +
                deviceId +
                "/version/" +
                versionId +
                "/file/" +
                fileId +
                "?processed=true"
        }).then(response => {
            if (response.data) return response.data;
        });
    } catch (err) {
        toast({
            message: err,
            flavor: "error",
            options: { isHtml: true }
        });
    }
};
```

This is component where I am calling:

```
/**
 * Get startup and running config file data and update state
 */
getConfigArchiveFileIDsData = (deviceId, archiveData) => {
    try {
        getConfigArchiveFileRawData(
            deviceId,
            archiveData.currentVersionID,
            archiveData.runningFileID
        ).then(data => {
            const getRunningConfigArchiveFileRawData = data;
            if (getRunningConfigArchiveFileRawData) {
                getConfigArchiveFileRawData(
                    deviceId,
                    archiveData.previousVersionID,
                    archiveData.startUpFileID
                ).then(data => {
                    const getStartupConfigArchiveFileRawData = data;
                    if (getStartupConfigArchiveFileRawData) {
                        this.setState({
                            startupConfigData: getStartupConfigArchiveFileRawData,
                            runningConfigData: getRunningConfigArchiveFileRawData,
                            showLoader: false
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    } catch (err) {
        toast({
            message: err,
            flavor: "error",
            options: { isHtml: true }
        });
    }
};
```

This issue is only coming when the file size is more, for example 4.5 MB file with 100 000 lines,
We get the processed raw file from api and then we pas these files to some component to evaluate.

**Update**

Getting this error also in console:

> unstable_flushDiscreteUpdates: Cannot flush updates when React is already rendering.

Comment: I would add some logging to find the exact position of the problem. Maybe it has to to with calling setState two times and the first call forces React to start rendering.
I am a Vue guy, so thats only guessing.

Comment: I guess That could be the issue,

Comment: @dec I tried to not call setState again and again but issue still persists, updated my code.

Comment: What are you doing inside setState? What did the logging/debugging shows? After what line is react logging this error? To make the code more readable use async/await and if you want to wait for both use Promise.all.